# Error while running Expo-ReactNative app in Iphone Simulator

Tags: react-native, expo, mobile-development

I have an expo-React native project. The Project is getting build correctly and i am able to generate .apk and .ipa files for it.

But when I try to run the app in the iPhone simulator. I am getting the below error:-

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSBundle must contain the expected assets'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this issue and turned out to be my own fault due to changes I'd made in AppDelegate.m.

These caused `[self initializeReactNativeApp];` to not be called when building for DEBUG.

Make sure *initializeReactNativeApp* is being called correctly in `application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in your app delegate.